# Discord.js - Get a random user with a reaction

Tags: node.js, random, bots, discord.js

So I made a giveaway and I want to get a random user who reacts to , but it didn't work.

```
bot.channels.get(giveawayChannelid).fetchMessage(messageID)
    .then(message => {  
      let reaction = message.reactions.find(r => r.emoji.name == '');
  if (reaction) {
      var randomUser = reaction.users.random(1);
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
        bot.channels.cache // make sure you use cache object
            .get(giveawayChannelid)
    .messages.fetch(messageID) // fetchMessage is deprecated with v12, use messages.fetch instead
                .then(message => {  
                  let reaction = message.reactions.cache // cache object 
            .find(r => r.emoji.name == '');
              if (reaction) {
                  reaction
                    .users.cache.array() // get all users who reacted
                    .filter((u) => !u.bot) // filter out bots
                    .random(); // get random user
               }
        });
```

Comment: it doesnt function because of 'Cannot read property 'get' of undefined'

Comment: what version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: the latest version of it (1.47.3)

Comment: Hm, that's weird. I'm also using the latest discord.js version and this worked for me.

Comment: but I use fetchMessage because message.fetch doesnt work

Comment: fetchMessage is deprecated in v12+

Comment: but I think the problem is cache after bot.channels because after deleting it it "worked" but I got only [object Promise] back

Comment: I installed the latest version of discord.js but I dont have message.fetch

Comment: I'm so sorry, my original answer had a typo. It's supposed to be **messages**.fetch, not message.fetch

Comment: var x=bot.channels.cache.get(giveawayChannelid).messages.fetch(messageID)
 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined  | Thats the error

Comment: I assume bot is defined as something like ``const bot = new Discord.Client``, right?

Comment: Type error: reaction.users.cache.array().filter((u) => !u.bot).random(); is not a function

Comment: My bad, remove the `array()` function. Just use `cache.filter(...)`

Comment: just wanted to elaborate on here, fetchMessages (plural!!) is deprecated in v12, fetchMessage (in order to get a single message) is still the way to go, messages.fetch returns all messages and from there you can pick the one you want, fetchMessage is more efficient and works in v12. I have used this last week and came here for something else, but thought I might as well share my findings

Comment: No, `fetchMessage` is very much [deprecated](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#fetch) in v12. Furthermore, if you only pass in a message ID, `messages.fetch` will return *one* message, not multiple.